# metadata file for Windows 8 Store app is not working well?

Tags: windows-8, portable-class-library

I am having issue during development of windows 8 store app, whenever i modified the project i got this issue.

```
Error   11  The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocketControl'. The use of the Windows namespace is reserved.   
Error   12  The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Networking.Sockets.IControlChannelTrigger'. The use of the Windows namespace is reserved.    
Error   13  The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Networking.Sockets.ISocketErrorStatics'. The use of the Windows namespace is reserved.
```

i have 3136 such errors i believe it has something with PCL and Windows namespace, i rename my project which contains string 'windows8' but still getting same. I reinstall my SDK and get the latest SDK but still nothing works. Now i have only option to reinstall my OS. Anyone know how to get out of it. Thanks

these are the references i use

[image]

Comment: I don't understand: why did you rename your project and reinstall your SDK?  I'm assuming you're seeing this error at compilation, and it quite clearly states the cause of the problem, and suggests that you're using classes from namespaces that aren't valid for a store app.  WinRT applications can only use a subset of the .NET framework, and it seems you're using more than that.

Comment: No i am not referring any such namespace,In VS2012 solution manage itself what references should be there for store app anyway i am able to deploy it few times but this issue occur suddenly without any major modification

Comment: It could be that you're referencing it indirectly.  But, you suggest that you deploy successfully before this error occurs: what change *did* you make when the error appeared?

Comment: i have noticed that winmd is reconstruct every-time i modify something...it make separate copy in bin folder of the project and i believe this is why i am getting this issue, winmd should not be their in bin folder as it is referencing to .net framework in c: drive too

Comment: I'm sorry you are encountering these issues. The fact that is being copied to your bin folder is likely the cause of this. Does this repro with a new Windows Store app or just in your application? Either way, can you turn on a diagnostic build (Environment -> Project and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity) and attach that to a bug report over on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio?

Comment: Oh...i just forget this question. I solve this issue, later i found that this issue is due to GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Win8 as they are also referencing to windows namespace which create ambiguity, so i just use alias to that reference and set its property Copy Local to FALSE. :) and that's it...Thanks for concern